# not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when I use argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to pass a dict (as a string) as an argument to a python script. when i run it from terminal I get an error

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

From terminal this I run :

```
python3 "./cleanuplogs.py" --dict='{"a":["anv", "huj"], "s":["dc", "dc"]}'
```

Could someone be able to help me fix this error. Below is the python script

```
import argparse
import subprocess as sp
import json

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dict', help='Directory and Files', 
    required=True, type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        for folder, files in json.loads(args.dict):
            for file in files:
                sp.call(["rm -r", folder+file])
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation, and provide the full error? And show an example of your input.

Comment: the argument is called `dict`, yet you're providing `path` on command line? Should it not be `--dict='{"a":["anv", "huj"], "s":["dc", "dc"]}'`

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace so we can see which line fails? Not this problem, but that should be `sp.call(["rm", "-rf", os.path.join(folder, file))`.

Comment: It would help if you told us which line is mentioned in the traceback. Or if it is from the try: except

Comment: Hey Sorry, that was a mistake. I edited my question with command line argument

Comment: Its probably `for folder, files in json.loads(args.path):`... try `print(json.loads(args.path))` to see what it returns. And, there isn't an `args.path` (its `args.dict`) so the code you show is raising a different error.

Comment: Also, just catching `Exception` looses important information. You could use the traceback module, `traceback.print_exc()` to get more info.

Comment: print us the command you're trying to execute to make sure it's well-formed and exists (like, what is providing a slash between `folder+file`?). Also show us the exact Exception with `traceback.print_exc()`

Answer (score 0):

This part is where I think the problem is:

```
try:
    for folder, files in json.loads(args.dict):
        for file in files:
            sp.call(["rm -r", folder+file])
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

The problem is in the 'for' statement json.loads returns a dict and it is this that is the one thing that is unpacked. you need to change the 'for' statement to read:

```
for folder, file in enumerate(json.loads(args.dict)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the module [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) and its function literal_eval() to convert to a dict, then use items() method to iterate over (key, value) pairs. Like so:

```
import argparse
import subprocess as sp
import ast

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dict', help='Directory and Files', required=True, type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        for folder, files in ast.literal_eval(args.dict).items():
            for file in files:
                sp.call(["rm -r", folder+file])
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```